# memory allocation error while using mclapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

it's the first i use mclapply to run parallel script on multiple process, but the problem that i've tried the script on my laptop and it worked very well and filled the `dataframe` correctly, but now when i run the script on my `office pc`, when the printing ends and it's time to collect the data, the script stops with this error :

> ```
> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 80 Kb
> ```

```
    fun <- function(testdf) {
  l=12000
    errordf=data.frame()
    errordf <- mclapply(1:nrow(15000), function(i)
    {
    for (ind in 1:nrow(testdf)) 
       {
        if( i >= l/2 ){
            testdf[ind,]$X =  testdf[ind,]$pos * 2
        } else 
        {
            testdf[ind,]$X = testdf[ind,]$pos/l
        }
    }

    permdf <- testdf
   lapply(1:100, function(j)
    {   permdf$X<- sample(permdf$X,nrow(permdf), replace=FALSE)
            fit=lm(X ~ gx, permdf)   #linear regression calculation
             regerror=sum(residuals(fit)^2)

        data.frame(pc=i,error=regerror )
     })

}, mc.cores=3)
res<-NULL
tmp <- lapply(errordf, function(ii){
    tmp <- lapply(ii, function(ij){    #rbind the data and return the dataframe
        res<<- rbind(res, ij)
    })
})
return (res)
    }
```

**testdf example:**

```
structure(list(ax = c(-0.0242214, 0.19770304, 0.01587302, -0.0374415, 
0.05079826, 0.12209738), gx = c(-0.3913043, -0.0242214, -0.4259067, 
-0.725, -0.0374415, 0.01587302), pos = c(11222, 13564, 16532, 
12543, 12534, 14354)), .Names = c("ax", "gx", "pos"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

i'm sure that the code is working (that's why i did not included the full code), because i tried it multiple times on my laptop, but when i tries it on my office pc it lunch this error.

any help would be appreciatd

Comment: Do package versions match on both PCs? What operating systems are you using?

Comment: currently i don't have my laptop, but it's a `macbook pro` and i think i have all the new packages. and my office pc is `fedora 16` and on the office pc, i have `R version 2.15.2`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik is there maybe a way to structure the lapply functions in a better way to avoid the memory problem? maybe replace 1 lapply with a for loop or so ??

Comment: How much memory do your office pc and macbook have. Do you run 64 bit OS on both machines?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra my macbook pro has 4GB of ram, and the office pc have 6GB, but i found out that the script sometimes gives the same error on the macbook..

Comment: You should check out Patrick Burns' R inferno. We could perhaps take a crack at this if we had a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you don't use the apply as intended in you last double nested `lapply` loop, you might as well use a `for` loop instead of using lapply combined with a global variable. In addition, you continuously grow `res`, this is rather memory and time intensive. Normally, an `lapply` loop would not suffer from this problem, but your use of a global variable totally negates the advantage. You seem to have a double nested list you want to `rbind`. I would defintely not loop over the data structure, I would just use something along the lines of  `do.call("rbind", data_structure)` to do this, although it is hard to provide concrete advice without a reproducible example. This solution does not suffer from the continuous growing problem you experience.

Comment: can you please give an example on how should i update the code ? at least how not to fall in the nested lapply thing ..?

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example, I could provide some code.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code and added a part of the dataframe, hope this is helpfull ..